# NextJS environment variables are undefined in the client-side while using `NEXT_PUBLIC_`

Tags: reactjs, next.js, environment-variables

Event with having prefixed all client-side exposed variables with `NEXT_PUBLIC` verifying them results in error. **The server-side does not complain about missing variables.**

NextJS Version: `12.2.5`

`.env.development`

```bash
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://dbuser:dbpass@localhost:5432/db?schema=public"
NEXT_PUBLIC_STATIC_MUSTER_URL="http://localhost:8080/muster"
NEXT_PUBLIC_MUSTER_SEARCH_HOST="http://localhost:7777"
NEXT_PUBLIC_MUSTER_SEARCH_API_KEY ="key"
NEXT_PUBLIC_NEWS_API_KEY="another_key"
NEXT_PUBLIC_NEWS_API_URL="http://localhost:8888"
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL="http://localhost:3000"
```

`utils/env.ts`

```js
function defaultValidator(key: string) {
    const value = process.env[key];

    if (value) {
        return value;
    }

    throw new Error(`Environment variable ${key} was not defined!`);
}

export const env = {
    NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    // DATABASE_URL: defaultValidator("DATABASE_URL"), // results in client error
    NEXT_PUBLIC_STATIC_MUSTER_URL: defaultValidator("NEXT_PUBLIC_STATIC_MUSTER_URL"), // results in client error
    NEXT_PUBLIC_MUSTER_SEARCH_HOST: defaultValidator("NEXT_PUBLIC_MUSTER_SEARCH_HOST"),
    NEXT_PUBLIC_MUSTER_SEARCH_API_KEY: defaultValidator("NEXT_PUBLIC_MUSTER_SEARCH_API_KEY"),
    NEXT_PUBLIC_NEWS_API_KEY: defaultValidator("NEXT_PUBLIC_NEWS_API_KEY"),
    NEXT_PUBLIC_NEWS_API_URL: defaultValidator("NEXT_PUBLIC_NEWS_API_URL"),
    NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL: defaultValidator("NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL"),
}
```

`pages/test.tsx`

```js
import {env} from 'utils/env'
default export function Test() {
   return (<div>{JSON.stringify({url: env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STATIC_MUSTER_URL})}</div>)
}
```

Client-Side error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Environment variable NEXT_PUBLIC_STATIC_MUSTER_URL was not defined!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#loading-environment-variables), this approach won't work because:

> Note: In order to keep server-only secrets safe, environment variables are evaluated at build time, so only environment variables actually used will be included. This means that process.env is not a standard JavaScript object, so you’re not able to use object destructuring. Environment variables must be referenced as e.g. process.env.PUBLISHABLE_KEY, not const { PUBLISHABLE_KEY } = process.env.

Comment: Thanks! I solved it by checking every time with the `defaultValidator` function before I use a variable. Not the prettiest approach IMHO.

Comment: you can try the solution suggested by Danila, it may work for you

Comment: This finally solves the problem on my client side.